# How to delete a file from the SD card within the python code?

Tags: sd-card

I'm working on a project where ten images are saved to the SD card and then sent to the computer via wifi. I want to save the images to the SD Card only for a few seconds. After they are sent I want to delete them off the SD Card. How do I this? And to be clear I want to do this within the python code.

In Arduino the line is:

sd.delete(file);

Comment: not Raspberry Pi specific ... general python programming question ... many examples are available about deleting files in linux

Answer (score 1):

A simple search on Google with "python delete files" reveals that it is something along the lines of:

```
import os
os.remove("ChangedFile.csv")
print("File Removed!")
```

(https://www.dummies.com/programming/python/how-to-delete-a-file-in-python/)